# Azure DevOPs Pipeline Error while using SlefHosted Agent Pool

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have been using Azure DevOps Pipeline for all our CICD, We have An Azure Webapp which is configured with private endpoint, with said i can only access it from Internal network. In this scenario, i can't use Azure agentpool for DevOps Pipeline, hence we deployed a Selfhosted agent and ran the pipeline using selfhosted agent. While using Selfhosted agent, we are getting an error message as below.

**2023-04-19T19:38:43.0799087Z ##[error]Error: Error: Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://azurewebapi.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd?site=syneossctqaapi'.
Error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Error count: 1.**

My Agent Pool is running with latest **TLS Version** and my Azure Webapp also configured with **Latest TLS version. 1.2. **

Any help much appreciated.

To test it, i changed agent pool from SelfHosted Agent pool to azure agent pool and i could be able to run the pipleline. I did deploy a new selfhosted VM changed the pipeline to new VM and still having same issue.